# Choose a value at random from a list, then use this value in a SOAP Request TestStep

Tags: random, groovy, soapui

I have a short list of values: [Option_1, Option_2, Option_3].

For each loop of my test, I want to pick a value from this list at random and assign it to a variable that I can then use in a Soap test step.

I've got a Groovy Script TestStep:

```
def z = ["Option_1", "Option_2", "Option_3"]
Random rnd = new Random()

def option = z[rnd.nextInt(z.size)]

testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue( "selectedOption", option )
```

In my Soap Test Step, I attempt to call the variable like so:

```
<value>${#selectedOption}</value>
```

Am I even close here? I'm extremely new to both SoapUI and Groovy. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Looks sensible apart from `z.size` needs to be `z.size()`... What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is right and producing the various values correctly as can be seen below

[image]

But the way you are trying to access the property should be done in below way.

Since you are trying to access a **testcase** property. You should use below syntax

```
<value>${#TestCase#selectedOption}</value>
```

This **TestCase** keyword is missed. Hope you are using this property at test case level. if you want to use in different test cases, you can set at suite level and then use ${TestSuite#selectedOption}

Comment: Thank you Gaurav, the TestCase keyword was the crucial bit of info I was missing. I think the code you gave me was missing a # symbol before 'TestCase', but the following worked perfectly!

`<value>${#TestCase#selectedOption}</value>`

Comment: Could you please accept this as Answer ? i have made the # correction

Answer (score 1):

actually SOAPUI (Pro) provides a possibility of generating random data in a loop.
If you use a DataSource Loop, you can use "Data Generator" as a DataSource. I tried quickly and this could fit your requirements.

Create a DataSource step:

- create a property (ie. output)
- select Data Generator as DataSource
- number of rows = 1
- Property type : Value from Set
- Custom values :

  - add/click in the Custom values field : Option_1
    idem for Option_2 then Option_3
  - add/click one more time (empty field) => I don't know why it works like this but if you don't do it, random will take into account only the two first data
- Generation mode : Random

If you launch that loop, the content of 'output' will, randomly, be one of your Custom values.
Then, you will just have to use the output property as you usually do for other steps (as you are new to SOAP UI, in the steps that will use the random value, click right and do 'Get Data' on the DataSource step to use the random output)

you may also be interested in having a look at this [use case](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Pro/Randomizing-DataSource-rows-data-loops-gets-stuck/td-p/128396)

good luck ;)

Comment: This looks great, and a much more streamlined way of handling randomisation. I shall have to look into getting SoapUI Pro if we are to do further automation. Thank you!

Comment: oups ... indeed, I didn't ask if you were using pro version ;)